# Spring boot JPA enable or disable a column with property file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot library project that uses JPA to persist data to a database. I have a column in my entity that I want to be able to enable or disable using property file.

Something like

```
lib.<entity>.<column_name>.enable=true
```

If I set this property to true, the column will be enabled. If I set it to false, the column will be transient.

Is there any method to achive this functionality in spring boot jpa.

Comment: pretty sure spring boot does not have this function out of the box. Have to implement it by yourself by looking at hibernate source codes to see how they create the mapping data . happy to look into it for you if this question is provided with enough bounty.

Comment: You can do it with an orm.xml file to override the mapping. Map it how you want via annotations, and map it the other way (transient) in the orm.xml file, and then have your orm.xml file get picked up via properties (or just use a second persistence.xml and switch which one your application uses in spring config). Other providers (EclipseLink) allow dynamically modifying mappings though if you'd like to take that approach (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/metadatasource.htm#TLADG1122 ) which allows you to switch between persistence unit mappings at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen an annotation ConditionalOnProperty, please check [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty) once.

```
@Column
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "Column", havingValue = "true")
```

Comment: That will definitly not work.